# MySQL Timestamp - Display 3 Rows within last hour

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How would I display rows that have a timestamp value within the last hour?

Here is what I have right now, and it is showing the latest rows, and only 3 rows because of the LIMIT.

```
$query5= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `made_orders` ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,3");



    WHILE($datarows5 = mysql_fetch_array($query5)):

    $name4 = $datarows5['Name'];
    $phone4 = $datarows5['Phone'];
    $entree4 = $datarows5['Entree'];
    $side14 = $datarows5['Side 1'];
    $side24 = $datarows5['Side 2'];
    $drink4 = $datarows5['Drink'];
    $totalcost4 = $datarows5['Total Cost'];
    $ip4 = $datarows5['Ip'];
    $id4 = $datarows5['id'];
    $time4 = $datarows5['timestamp'];

    echo "<iframe src=\"creatmeal-data.php?id={$id4}\" width=\"430px\" style=\"border:0px\" height=\"350px\"/></iframe>";

endwhile; ?>
```

In my above code, each time a row is found, it echos an iframe. How would I edit the query to use my timestamp column to show only the latest within an hour.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Here is what my timestamp column looks like: http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/4135/columnk.png

Comment: You do that through a simple WHERE (conditional) statement. Since you didn't specify what kind of timestamp (Unix, SQL, etc) you use, I can't give you a definitive answer, but it would if it were unix, it would look something like this: `SELECT * FROM made_orders WHERE timestamp > '".time()-3600."' ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your current query gets the three most recent orders regardless of whether or not they were created in the last hour.

Use this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM made_orders
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

This would get at most three orders within the last hour. If there was only one order within the last hour, it would only select one row.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM  `made_orders` ORDER by id WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`yourTimestampColumn`) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60*60